# Is there a way to emulate a specefic vendor OS such as huawei's emui

Tags: android

My app works fine on most devices however there seems to be some issues on some phones because of the manufacturer's software especially their power settings. Unfortunately, I don't have access to these physical devices, Is there a way to emulate them for debugging and testing purposes?